# I getting an error when I use cdn sockets.io

Tags: sockets, express

I am creating a web app with express and sockets.io, but when I try to include sockets.js using a CDN, I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

In the `index.html` I am including the scripts this way:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src = js/app.js>
```

In the `app.js` I control the client-side this way:

```
var socket  = io();
$('form').submit(function(){
  socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
  $('#m').val('');
  return false;
});
```

And in the server I respond with this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log(msg)
  });
});
```

How can I include sockets in the client-side?

Comment: If you're running a `socket.io` server, why not use the client code that the server provides already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this problem is new, it's probably because socketio's SSL cert expired today (5/27/16). You can use `<script src="http://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>` instead temporarily while they fix it.